# Issues when using Ajax for post request on WordPress plugin

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm working on submitting a post request using Ajax in my WordPress plugin. My JavaScript looks like this:

```
var file_data = $("#fileID").prop("files")[0];
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append("action", "my_function");
form_data.append("file", file_data);

$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "' . admin_url("admin-ajax.php") . '",
 cache: false,
 dataType: "json",
 processData: false,
 data: form_data,
 success: function(php_script_response) {
       alert(php_script_response); // display response from the PHP script, if any
 },
 error: function(response) {
          alert(response);
 }
});
```

I have added two add_action's for my function (in my plugin's php file) like this:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_function', 'my_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_function', 'my_function');
```

My function isn't getting called unless I use data: form_data + "&action=my_function", but then I don't have any data available in the function.

How can I correctly get this request sent with my data?

Comment: I have answered similar question some time ago. Maybe it'll help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/244089/passing-jquery-value-to-wordpress-function/244102#244102

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek The only thing I can think of is that I'm not doing step 2. How can I include my php file in functions.php? Do I need to give a path or anything to my plugin?